# How to checkout a project from GitHub and build it through command line and use it in eclipse workspace for edit?

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, build-automation

As an initial step, checking out a project from GitHub and building it through eclipse taking too much time in my case, I decided to automate that initial process through command line. And I'm able to do that successfully.

But I wanted use that imported project in Eclipse for further edits. This I don't know how to do. Can you please help me in achieving it

Comment: Do you mean, how to create an Eclipse workspace and then import that project automatically?

Comment: @AIBlue Yes. Exactly.

Comment: Well it depends on how much you want to automate. If you just have one project then you could create a new project in eclipse (empty) and then close eclipse. If you then check your project out into the same place as the eclipse project then when you open eclipse it sold automatically build it. Of course if it have lots of projects this might not be feasible. If you can’t open eclipse but want to build it manually then you could look at build tools like maven or gradle which will do the build for you.